# Spinner, string-array onclick performance

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

I am making a self service form with a set of questions during user registration.

Here is the string.xml file

```
<resources>
sources>
 <string name="question1">What was your childhood nickname?</string>
<string name="question2">What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?</string>
<string name="question3">In what city or town did your mother and father meet?</string>
<string name="question4">What is your favorite team?</string>
<string name="question5">What was your favorite sport in high school?</string>
<string name="question6">What was your favorite food as a child?</string>
<string name="question7">What was the make and model of your first car?</string>
<string name="question8">What is you mother\'s maiden name?</string>
<string name="question9">In which city/town were you born?</string>
<string name="question10">In what town/city was your first job?</string>

<string-array name="questions">
    <item>Select a question</item>
    <item>@string/question1</item>
    <item>@string/question2</item>
    <item>@string/question3</item>
    <item>@string/question4</item>
    <item>@string/question5</item>
    <item>@string/question6</item>
    <item>@string/question7</item>
    <item>@string/question8</item>
    <item>@string/question9</item>
    <item>@string/question10</item>
</string-array>
```

I have pulled these questions into 3 different spinners in the activity xml file.

activity_self_service.xml

```
  Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_q1);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_q2);
    Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_q3);

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.questions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.questions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.questions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner1.setPrompt("Select a security question");
    spinner2.setPrompt("Select a security question");
    spinner3.setPrompt("Select a security question");
     // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);
```

Say the user selected question 3, question 5 and question 6 in 3 different spinners, I want to store the indexes of these questions and the answers in the database.

So, I want something like (3,answer 1) ,(5, answer 2), (6, answer 3) in the DB.

I tried to get the indexes but couldnt find a way. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set "OnItemSelectedListener" on all your spinners, it will give you the index when an item is selected.